# How to get information about end of execution some asynchronous method in javascript which dont provide this option

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, methods, jquery-deferred

How to get information about end of execution some asynchronous method in javascript which dont provide this option. Example: i use jtable library and need to know about time then method .jtable('load') will complete. Changing library code is unacceptable. What i am gonna do ?

Comment: Read the documentation and/or the source code if it’s open sourced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a callback functon in .load:

```
$('#Table').jtable(
    'load',
    {
        cityId: 1,
        name: 'London',
        data: 'information'
    },
    function(){
        alert('.load function successfully completed');
});
```

Comment: Great thanks for  help, i tried to do this: $('#Table').jtable('load', function () { alert('some alert'); }); but this dont work. Now i get it ! )

Comment: Ark, you have asked a generalized question illustrated with an example - and accepted an answer that addresses the example without attempting to address the generality. If this answer genuinely solves your issue, then the question should be amended. If not, then you should un-accept the answer.